# iOS custom view with properties that involve layout cycle: one struct vs several properties?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm building a custom view that has several configuration options, each of them, upon being changed, will lead to a re-layout, so I wonder, if I should group them in one struct so that change of 1 or multiple configurations will result in one single layout calculation, versus several properties but each can trigger a separate work for re-calculating the layout.

For example:

```swift
class MyView {
  var textDirection: TextDirection = .leftToRight
  var scrollType: ScrollType = .continuous
}
```

vs:

```swift
class MyViewConfiguration {
  let textDirection: TextDirection {
    didSet {
      updateLayout()
    }
  }
  let scrollType: ScrollType {
    didSet {
      updateLayout()
    }
  }
}

class MyView {
  var configuration: MyViewConfiguration {
    didSet {
      updateLayout()
    }
  }
}
```

It seems obvious to me that one single configuration is more efficient, the only downside is probably that whenever any configuration changes I need to re-create and pass the whole configuration object.

Is there any other benefit for the first approach with separated configuration options?

Thanks!

Comment: It's very difficult to help with questions that are asked "in the abstract." We have no idea what your `updateLayout()` func may be doing, so there is no way anyone could even try to say one approach is better than the other.

Comment: The question you must ask yourself is : when do you want to change the layout ? When one setting changes, when user has changed multiple settings from another view ? In the latter case you must signal that the settings had changed to the view to update. (ViewWillAppear, notification, …)